# Check if checkbox was checked without form or javaScript in RoR

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have а checkbox in the view, it's not binded to form. Can I send it's state through `params` to my controller or helper or whatever when I click on a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest a process as per your need is like,

1. make a input type checkbox(need not to bind it with any form) and give it a "id" attribute(html) to uniquely identify it on the DOM.
2. make a link with "#" target and do a Ajax call on the click
3. on this ajax call check the value of checkbox in js by using its id and send it to controller using ajax request and perform action according to value of the checkbox sent to the controller.

Comment: Well I get the main idea, but is there any way to do it without javaScripting? Not that I'm unfamiliar with it. But if browser is blocking js, there wil be no way to pass it. Am I right?

Comment: if u want to check checkbox on client side then U will need JS for sure. and tell me why browser will block js?

Comment: Well I don't want to check exactly on client side, I just want to check its state. Blocking js is just for example.

Comment: but how can u check before loading ur view(page) in the browser?

Comment: But there is sime way to pass it to another page by submitting form with `Submit` button? Why can't I pass it to page, but with **link**, not button?

Comment: yes u can do it using a hidden form, and on click of the link just call a single line js function. it will be very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing specific to Ruby on Rails.

You can use the `onchange` event on the checkbox to trigger an action. And almost always, the action is a call to a javascript function.

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction();">
```

Inside `myFunction()` you can build a querystring and make an `ajax` call. This is how you can pass the value to a rails action or any other CGI script on the backend.

Also have a look at this [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_checkbox.asp)

Comment: Well, I know about `onChange` event, but how to pass state of checkbox to action? Do I need to attach function, that just changes link directly?

Comment: Yes. In the javascript stitch together the query string, and append it to the url of the action. For example: '/url/of/action? Checkboxname=val&another_attribute=another_value'. Use this to make an ajax call.